# Trying to access current user in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Is there a way to get access to the current_user in rails admin config.model filterable option. I have tried using:

```
bindings[:view]._current_user
```

but bindings is nil for me

Here's a code snippet of what I've been doing:

```
field :user do
  filterable do                     #I want to access current user here
    bindings[:view]._current_user   #bindings is nil
  end

  pretty_value do
    bindings[:view]._current_user   #bindings is not nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't access it via the bindings approach so I just made a before filter in my application controller that calls a method there which sets the current user in my User model via a class method.

Thus, in my code snippet, I could access current_user like so:

```
...
filterable do
User.current
end
...
```

Answer came from this:
https://amitrmohanty.wordpress.com/2014/01/20/how-to-get-current_user-in-model-and-observer-rails/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use:

```rb
      field :user_id do
        default_value do
          bindings[:controller].current_user
        end
      end
```